# Search for links and add suffix

Tags: php

I need to add a suffix to all URLs on a website, I'm dealing with a little problem as I'm using a WordPress plugin that allows me to use different templates by defining a variable but of course WP doesn't recognize this so I need to create a function on the second template that adds a "?theme=2" to all the links on the page.

Is this possible with PHP?

Comment: My first thought might be to try [.htaccess rewrites](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215747748-How-can-I-redirect-and-rewrite-my-URLs-with-an-htaccess-file-), if you happen to be hosting WP on an Apache server...

Comment: How many links? What is the format? Are there spaces at the end? Please provide code.